# js Graph using Map class - where to store weight?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graph, weighted-graph

I've looked at a dozen examples but can't find any of a weighted graph using the JS Map object (except one with no weight).

Is there a preferred place to put the weight?

Here are the basic class structures:

```
/**
 * @typedef {any} NodeData The Vertex data and used as a key in lists.
 * @typedef {Map<NodeData, Vertex>} AdjacencyList
 */

class Vertex {
  constructor(data) {
    this.data = data;
    /**
     * @type {AdjacencyList}
     */
    this.edges = new Map();
  }
}

class Graph {
  constructor() {
    /**
     * @type {AdjacencyList}
     */
    this.vertices = new Map();
}
```

I can't put the weight in my `Vertex` class I think since the same vertex can be an edge of many others by reference so it needs to be able to have different weights.

My idea is to make an `Edge` class like so:

```
class Edge {
  /**
   * @param {Vertex} point
   * @param {number} weight The cost to travel to this point.
   */
  constructor(point, weight) {
    this.point = point;
    this.weight = weight;
  }
}
```

However, this is a bit annoying for things like listing the nodes in a path, because of mixing data types `Vertex` and `Edge` since you start at a `Vertex` first. To avoid this it starts getting less elegant and I feel like I'm missing something. For example I could put the first `Vertex` visited into a new `Edge` instance with a `0` weight so I can have a list of all `Edge` types returned.

Also, for undirected, this means the same weight value is duplicated to both sides which makes me wonder if that's supposed to be avoided.

Appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't key that `edges` map by the data of the node it is pointing at. That would make updating the data of a node a real hazzle. Instead, use a `Map<Vertex, Weight>` for your edges.

An alternative would be to use two maps: `neighbors: Map<key, Vertex>` and `weights: Map<key, Weight>`, where you ensure in your methods that the key set is kept in sync. Notice however that a normal `AdjacencyList` is just a list, it is not keyed at all.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense about the updating hassle since it wouldn't update by ref.